# Execute Command after hit Enter in a inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Mojarra 2.1.5 / PrimeFaces 3.5

I dont know how to explain that.I have one inputText and commandButton
When I type something in inputText and hit Enter I need the commandButton be executed automatically.

```
<p:inputText id="txtProducao" required="false"
    value="#{ManagedBean.xxxPreco.producaoDia}"
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.xxPreco_xProdx}>
</p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="buttonProducaoDia" 
    icon="ui-icon-check"
    actionListener="#{ManagedBean.calculaProdxxx}"
    update="txtValorSoma">
</p:commandButton>
```

**I need to type some value for each inputText and after hit Enter I need the respective commandButton be executed :**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a single `p:commandButton`, then pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> should submit the form. If you have many `p:commandButton` in the form. You can define the one which is the default submitted button by using the [`p:defaultCommand`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/defaultCommand.jsf).

```
<p:inputText id="txtProducao" required="false"
    value="#{ManagedBean.xxxPreco.producaoDia}"
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.xxPreco_xProdx}>
</p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="buttonProducaoDia" 
    icon="ui-icon-check"
    actionListener="#{ManagedBean.calculaProdxxx}"
    update="txtValorSoma">
</p:commandButton>
<p:defaultCommand target="buttonProducaoDia" />
```

[Edit]

I think that you have to solve it using JavaScript, like this:

```
<p:inputText id="txtProducao" required="false"
    value="#{ManagedBean.xxxPreco.producaoDia}"
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.xxPreco_xProdx}>
    <p:ajax event="keydown" update="@form" onstart="if (event.keyCode != 13) { return false; }" />
</p:inputText>
```

You can also add an `actionListener` to the `p:ajax` element. In JavaScript, you could also call a submit.

Comment: I have 10 inputText and commandButton. Each CommandButton is located after each inputText. How can I do to type something in each inputText and hitting Enter execute the related commandButton ?

Comment: do you have some clue how can I do regarding the first comment I did ? thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm unfortunately not sure if there is not a better solution.